# Cpp:: Custom Exceptions, Variable Message not caught (<< operator)

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling, macros, try-catch

Hi there i am currently having a Problem with my Exception class/macro.

So first a Sample file to show what i do mean.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class ExceptionHelper : public std::exception {
public:
  ExceptionHelper(std::string msg) : std::exception(), msg_(msg) {}

  ExceptionHelper operator<<(std::string const &value) {
    msg_.append(" :: ");
    msg_.append(value);
    return ExceptionHelper(msg_);
  }

  virtual const char *what() const throw() { return msg_.c_str(); }

private:
  std::string msg_;
};

#define DEFINE_EXCEPTION(ClassName, Message)                                   \
  class ClassName : public ExceptionHelper {                                   \
  public:                                                                      \
    ClassName(std::string msg = Message) : ExceptionHelper(msg) {}             \
  };

DEFINE_EXCEPTION(Test, "Testmessage")

int main() {
  try {
    throw Test();
  } catch (Test &e) {
    std::cout << "I was caught 1 " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  try {
    throw(Test() << "Something added");
  } catch (Test &e) {
    std::cout << "I was caught 2 " << e.what();
  } catch (std::exception &e) {
    std::cout << "should not be called " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  try {
    Test t;
    t << "Something added";
    throw t;
  } catch (Test &e) {
    std::cout << "I was caught 3 " << e.what();
  } catch (std::exception &e) {
    std::cout << "should not be called2" << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Different Versions off << operator (that do no differnce to the output):

```
ExceptionHelper& operator<<(std::string const &value) {
        msg_.append(" :: ");
        msg_.append(value);
        return *this;
      }
ExceptionHelper operator<<(std::string const &value) {
            msg_.append(" :: ");
            msg_.append(value);
            return *this;
          }
```

Output:

```
I was caught 1 Testmessage
should not be called Testmessage :: Something added
I was caught 3 Testmessage :: Something added
```

Wanted Output:

```
I was caught 1 Testmessage
I was caught 2 Testmessage :: Something added
I was caught 3 Testmessage :: Something added
```

So i would like to create Special Exception Classes with my DEFINE_EXCEPTION macro which works great.

I now would like to add extra Info to an new exception type. (This would be handy for debugging since it would allow me to write something like throw Test() << "Variable x : " + std::to_string(x))

This is show in case 2 in the main method. Here only std::exception gets caught and not the Test exception.

if i do it like in the third example in the main it works fine.

I tried many styles on the << operator but i found non which makes a difference.

I would be interrested in a solution that allowes that syntax. Also info to why this is not working is welcome.

Comment: `operator<<` should probably do `return *this;` rather than creating a new object to return.

Comment: that was my first version and i did the same. I changed it since in the third example in the main it works. so i thaught maybe the problem is that the function returned a reference... but it did no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for that hint :)... long day.

Here if someone is interested in the working version.

```
class ExceptionHelper : public std::exception {
public:
  ExceptionHelper(std::string msg) : std::exception(), msg_(msg) {}
  virtual const char *what() const throw() { return msg_.c_str(); }

protected:
  std::string msg_;
};

#define DEFINE_EXCEPTION(ClassName, Message)                                   \
  class ClassName : public ExceptionHelper {                                   \
  public:                                                                      \
    ClassName(std::string msg = Message) : ExceptionHelper(msg) {}             \
                                                                               \
    template<class T>                                                          \
    ClassName &operator<<(T const &value) {                                    \
      msg_.append(" :: ");                                                     \
      msg_.append(value);                                                      \
      return *this;                                                            \
    }                                                                          \
  };
```

Comment: Can that be a template?

Comment: yes i actually did it as a template version and it works the same way.

Comment: Many people here would hug you for doing that.

Comment: You're going to add it to your answer?  Good.

Comment: i would love to do that but stackoverflow forces me to wait 2 days. i dont know why. I will do it when i am able to

Comment: Ah, OK, low rep, that will change.  @ me when it's done and I will upvote you.

Answer (score 0):

`ExceptionHelper::operator <<` is returning the type `ExceptionHelper` which is not been caught.

To test it add a catch for `ExceptionHelper`.

Define the `operator <<` in your `Class` to solve the problem.

Comment: Would it be better for it to return a reference, so it doesn't slice away the derived class when it returns?

Comment: No. You have to return the type that You want to catch. Or go into virtual functions and catch the ExceptionHelper pointer.

Comment: He wants `Test << "message"` to return a `Test` so that he can catch the same type that he's throwing.